# Scroll View with images in a Horizontal (like the Youtube App) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, youtube, uiscrollview

I want to learn Swift and I want to make an app with a ScrollView like it is in the YouTube App. 
[image: The ScrollView I want to make]

The scrollview I make in the storyboard.
I try it with this code:

```
let myImages = ["ImageGelb.png","ImageGrün.png","ImageRot.png"]
    let imageWidth:CGFloat = 66
    let imageHeight:CGFloat = 66
    var xPosition:CGFloat = 0
    var scrollViewSize:CGFloat=0

    var index=0
    index<=myImages.count
    index++

    let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: myImages[index])!
    let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    myImageView.image = myImage

    myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
    myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
    myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
    myImageView.frame.origin.y = 10

    ScrollViewNeuesFreunde.addSubview(myImageView)
    xPosition += imageWidth
    scrollViewSize += imageWidth

    ScrollViewNeuesFreunde.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewSize, height: imageHeight)
```

but it doesn´t work. Only the "ImageGrün.png" is on the screen and the ScrollView does´t work.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You are not incrementing your index except for one time. index = 0, then you incremented it with index++, giving you the picture at index 1 of your array. You want to use a for loop.

```
let myImages = ["ImageGelb.png","ImageGrün.png","ImageRot.png"]
    let imageWidth:CGFloat = 66
    let imageHeight:CGFloat = 66
    var xPosition:CGFloat = 0
    var scrollViewSize:CGFloat=0


    for image in myImages {
       let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: image)!
       let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
       myImageView.image = myImage

       myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
       myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
       myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
       myImageView.frame.origin.y = 10

       ScrollViewNeuesFreunde.addSubview(myImageView)
       xPosition += imageWidth
       scrollViewSize += imageWidth
    }
    ScrollViewNeuesFreunde.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewSize, height: imageHeight)
```

This way you don't need an index, as Swifts fast enumeration takes care of it for you. For more on this check out this link.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121